# How do you integrate MYOB Exo Business (Exonet) to a .NET application?

Tags: sql-server, myob

I'm currently exploring the possibility of integrating MYOB Exo Business (Exonet) to a shopping cart developed using ASP.NET 3.5. I understand that there is an MYOB ODBC driver to use as a connector. Is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck with MYOB Exo Business, as it runs on a SQL Server backend. You can connect directly to the database using all the normal tools.

UPDATE:
Since answering this question, MYOB have release a limited Restful API. More details can be found [here](http://developer.myob.com/api/exo/exo-api-overview/)

Comment: Thanks, I guess directly connecting to the database is the only way to do it now.